# How to find specific characters in a specific order in a string. Python

Tags: python, string, search

I have a csv with all the words from the dictionary, and i want to have a function that given three characters, searches for all the words from the csv that contain the given characters in the given order.

```py
def read_words(registro):
    with open(file, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        lector = csv.reader(f)
        palabras = [p for p in lector]
    return palabras

file= ("Diccionario.csv")

register = read_words(file)

def search_for_words_with(register, a, b, c):
    res = []
    for w in register:
        if a in w:
            if b in w:
                if c in w:
                    res.append(w)
    return res
```

Comment: Please show your work, what you have tried. I'm sorry, but SO is not a software writing service.

Comment: I uploaded what i have for now, srry in quite new on this.

Comment: Much better, thanks. Now, can you also indicate in what way it's not working, or any errors you are getting?

Comment: And ideally make the example a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which we can cut and paste and run to see the problem on our own computers. If the problem is with `search_for_words_with`, for example, you could give us a hard-coded `register` array and a call to the function that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Use a regexp: `firstchar.*secondchar.*thirdchar`

Comment: Your code checks that they're all in the word, but not in order.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex and list comprehension:

```
import regex as re

def search_for_words_with(register, a, b, c):
    words_with_a_b_c = [w for w in register if re.search(a + '.*' + b + '.*' + c, w)]
    return words_with_a_b_c

register = ['hello', 'worldee']
a, b, c = 'e', 'l', 'o'

words_with_a_b_c = search_for_words_with(register, a, b, c)
```

to get words_with_a_b_c

```
['hello']
```